# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException - org.openrdf.repository.config.RepositoryConfigException in JSF

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, tomcat, sesame

I am trying to run a `JSF` application on Tomcat 6 which is only for connecting to the Sesame repository. I added all the external `Jar` files needed for Sesame and the the project is created as `Dynamic Web Project` for `JSF`. I also configured everything for JSF by following some tutorials. In Eclipse, I export the `WAR` file to deploy it on `Tomcat 6` as follows:

```
Right-click on the project -> Export -> WAR file.
```

The `WAR` file is stored in `webapps` folder in `Tomcat`. When I insert the `URL`: `http://localhost:8080/JSFSesame/faces/index.jsp`, I get the following message:

```
An Error Occurred:
org/openrdf/repository/config/RepositoryConfigException

Caused by:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException - org.openrdf.repository.config.RepositoryConfigException
```

I do not know what is missing at this point. It seems like I need to add `JAR` files that I am not aware of. Could anyone please assist me to solve this problem? Your help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Class `RepositoryConfigException` is missing. 
It is e.g. part of the following JAR `sesame-repository-api-2.5.0.jar`.
Alternatively use `Ctrl+Shift+H` in eclipse and look, fro which jar it is retrieved from there - copy the jar.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I found this jar file. I copied this file from sesame-repository-api-2.6.0.and pasted it to the lib folder where the JSF application is located in Tomcat. I found similar error to the previous one. It seems I need to copy all these jar files and pasted them in the lib folder. Will let you know the result soon. Once again, thank you.

Comment: Am having another error: org.openrdf.repository.RepositoryException: <html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/6.0.37 - Error report</title><style> .... . Do you have any idea what that is all about?

Comment: Well, upvotes say "answer is useful", accept means "answer helped me solve the problem". The current exception is now possible after adding the correct jar ;-) You posted the HTML-part of it. More interesting is the stacktrace. You should open a new question for that... it's not related to the upper question anymore. Oh, yes, "accept" and "upvote" appreciated. :-)

Comment: I am so sorry. I did not understand what you meant. Thank you for your help. Will accept the answer soon.

Comment: Tested everything now. I had another issue and just fixed it. This is the right answer. Thank you very much for your assistance, L-Ray. It is very much appreciated.

Comment: Can I also suggest that this kind of thing becomes a whole lot easier if you switch to using a dependency management system like Maven, or Ivy. All Sesame jar files are available in Maven Central. See the [Sesame docs on library installation](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/docs/users.docbook?view#chapter-lib-install) for details.